# Prove that there is unique length metric on $X/G$ such that $\pi : X \rightarrow X/G$ is a local isometry

Tags: metric-spaces, group-actions, geometric-group-theory

Suppose $X$ is a length metric space and $G$ acts on $X$   by isometries properly discontinuously and the action is free. Then  there is unique length metric on $X/G$ such that $\pi : X \rightarrow X/G$ is a local isometry.

My attempt: Let $x, y \in X$, $\pi(x) = \bar{x}, \pi (y) =\bar{y}$.

Now I define $$\bar{d}(x,y) = d(\pi^{-1} (\bar{x}), \pi^{-1} (\bar{y})) = \text{inf}\{d(x^\prime, y^\prime) \mid x^\prime \in \pi^{-1} (\bar{x}), y^\prime \in  \pi^{-1} (\bar{y})\}$$

my thought is to claim $\bar{d}$ is the required metric. But I cannot approach properly. Please help.

Comment: Please correct the tex error and explain where did this problem come from.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't know what is correct group action symbol in latex? And this problem was in a graduate seminar that I attended. The speaker just told that it's an  exercise.

Comment: Maybe just writing "$G$ acts on $X$" is good enough? I can faintly remember seeing a symbol for it, but I don't think I would remember what it meant without an explanation.

Comment: You can always use the standard notation $G\times X\to X$ for an action.

Comment: Also, add the assumption that the action is free.